# Java: signed long to unsigned long string

Tags: java

Is there an easy and fast way to convert a Java signed long to an unsigned long string?

```
-1                    ->  "18446744073709551615"
-9223372036854775808  ->  "09223372036854775808"
 9223372036854775807  ->  "09223372036854775807"
 0                    ->  "00000000000000000000"
```

Comment: @parsifal http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twos_complement

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is a solution using BigInteger:

```
/** the constant 2^64 */
private static final BigInteger TWO_64 = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(64);

public String asUnsignedDecimalString(long l) {
   BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(l);
   if(b.signum() < 0) {
      b = b.add(TWO_64);
   }
   return b.toString();
}
```

This works since the unsigned value of a (signed) number in two-s complement is just 2<sup>(number of bits)</sup> more than the signed value, and Java's `long` has 64 bits.

And BigInteger has this nice `toString()` method which we can use here.

Answer (score 12):

Java 8 includes some support for unsigned longs.  If you don't need the  zero padding, just do:

```
Long.toUnsignedString(n);
```

If you need zero padding, formatting doesn't work for unsigned longs.  However this workaround does an unsigned divide by 10 to drop the unsigned value to a point where it can be represented without the sign bit in the long:

```
String.format("%019d%d", Long.divideUnsigned(n, 10), Long.remainderUnsigned(n, 10));
```

Answer (score 6):

### 1

Based on @Paŭlo Ebermann solution I came up with this one:

```
public static String convert(long x) {
    return new BigInteger(1, new byte[] { (byte) (x >> 56),
        (byte) (x >> 48), (byte) (x >> 40), (byte) (x >> 32),
        (byte) (x >> 24), (byte) (x >> 16), (byte) (x >> 8),
        (byte) (x >> 0) }).toString();
}
```

Using `new BigInteger(int signum, byte[] bytes);` makes BigInteger to read bytes as positive number (unsigned) and apply signum to it.

---

### 2

Based on @Chris Jester-Young solution I found this one:

```
private static DecimalFormat zero = new DecimalFormat("0000000000000000000");

public static String convert(long x) {
    if (x >= 0) // this is positive
        return "0" + zero.format(x);

    // unsigned value + Long.MAX_VALUE + 1
    x &= Long.MAX_VALUE;
    long low = x % 10 + Long.MAX_VALUE % 10 + 1;
    long high = x / 10 + Long.MAX_VALUE / 10 + low / 10;
    return zero.format(high) + low % 10;
}
```

---

### 3

Yet another way to do it:

```
private static DecimalFormat zero19 = new DecimalFormat("0000000000000000000");

public static String convert(long x) {
    if (x >= 0) {
        return "0" + zero19.format(x);
    } else if (x >= -8446744073709551616L) {
        // if:   x + 18446744073709551616 >= 10000000000000000000
        // then: x + 18446744073709551616 = "1" + (x + 8446744073709551616)
        return "1" + zero19.format(x + 8446744073709551616L);
    } else {
        // if:   x + 18446744073709551616 < 10000000000000000000
        // then: x + 18446744073709551616 = "09" + (x + 9446744073709551616)
        // so:   9446744073709551616 == -9000000000000000000L
        return "09" + (x - 9000000000000000000L);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd love to see whether the "no-`BigInteger`" version is faster than both versions, too. :-) (If I find some time today, I'll do some testing and post my results.)

Comment: @Chris see my no-BigInteger version! :)

Comment: +1 Very nice (re divide-by-10). That's probably the most straightforward way to do it.

Comment: I thought about writing something like your first version, but it was too complicated for my lazyness :-)

Answer (score 4):

Two years late, but here is a very compact solution that avoids `BigInteger` and byte arrays.
Basically it emulates unsigned division to extract one digit, and then it offloads the rest to the library function.

```
public static String unsignedToString(long n) {
    long temp = (n >>> 1) / 5;  // Unsigned divide by 10 and floor
    return String.format("%019d", temp) + (n - temp * 10);
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you'd like to avoid temporary strings and library functions altogether, then we can compute all the digits from first principles:

```
public static String unsignedToString(long n) {
    char[] buffer = new char[20];
    int i = buffer.length - 1;

    // Do first iteration specially
    long temp = (n >>> 1) / 5;  // Unsigned divide by 10
    buffer[i] = (char)(n - temp * 10 + '0');
    n = temp;

    // Do rest of iterations the normal way
    for (i--; i >= 0; i--) {
        buffer[i] = (char)(n % 10 + '0');
        n /= 10;
    }

    return new String(buffer);
}
```

Both implementations above are functionally equivalent, so you can pick the one you like best.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel and maintain your code, Guava might be an option:

```
formatted = UnsignedLong.fromLongBits(myLongValue).toString();
formatted = UnsignedLongs.toString(myLongValue);
```

References: [UnsignedLong](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedLong.html), [UnsignedLongs](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedLongs.html)

Answer (score 2):

I also have a non-`BigInteger`-based version (since having to reach out for `BigInteger` did bug me for a while); I've retained my `main` function for your ease of testing:

```
public class UlongToString {
    private static final String MIN_VALUE = "" + Long.MIN_VALUE;

    public static String ulongToString(long value) {
        long pos = value & Long.MAX_VALUE;
        if (value == pos)
            return String.valueOf(pos);

        char[] chars = MIN_VALUE.toCharArray();
        chars[0] = '0';
        for (int i = chars.length - 1; i != 0 && pos != 0; --i) {
            if ((chars[i] += pos % 10) > '9') {
                chars[i] -= 10;
                ++chars[i - 1];
            }
            pos /= 10;
        }
        int strip = '1' - chars[0];
        return new String(chars, strip, chars.length - strip);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        for (String arg : args) {
            System.out.println(ulongToString(Long.parseLong(arg)));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I just had this problem and solved it using this code:

```
String.format("%016x", x);
```

I am not sure if I am missing something but it seems a lot simpler this way.

Comment: so what does it output for -1l?

Comment: ffffffffffffffff ; I just realised that the original poster wanted a decimal string and not a hexadecimal string - my bad!