# Android support for parseUnsignedLong?

Tags: java, android, long-integer, unsigned

I want to treat a value of type Long as unsigned long. I have read that in Java 8 they added methods to do things like that. 
But when I try to use the new methods like:

```
long values = Long.parseUnsignedLong("18446744073709551615");
```

Android Studio gives me an error message like this:

> cannot resolve method parseUnsignedLong(java.lang.string)

Can I not use the Java 8 methods on an Android system?

What would be an alternative solution?

Comment: I think you don't have java 8 on Android yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 8 is supported only from Android N, the newest upcoming version of Android OS.Here some link about:

**Wikipedia**
[Wikipedia Android Nougat](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Nougat)

**Android devo per site**
[Android Java 8 features](https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html)

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 has not yet been implemented for Android. It will be arriving with the next version (Android N)

[Source](https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html)

As for an alternative, see the answer to this question [Java: signed long to unsigned long string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031198/java-signed-long-to-unsigned-long-string)